# Creating the method copied for IntoIterator

Tags: rust

First, I wanted a function which would take generic collections but wouldn't consume it. That is, we have a function `non_consuming`.

```rust
fn non_consuming<'a,I>(_: &'a I)
where &'a I: std::iter::IntoIterator<Item = usize> {}
```

For specific reasons I'm not able to change the `Item` requirement to `&usize`. Such the compiler throws an error if I wanted to use this method normally like so:

```rust
non_consuming(&vec![0usize,1,2]);
```

Because `IntoIterator` is implemented for `&Vec`, but with `Item = &T`. Such I had the idea of implementing something like [copied](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) but for `IntoIterator` instead of `Iterator`.

My goal was to create a method `into_copied` for any `IntoIterator` with `Item: &T` which returns a struct `C` implementing `IntoIterator` with `Item: T` **and** `&C` should also implement `IntoIterator` with `Item: T`.

I use an extension trait to implement `into_copied` for any `IntoIterator` and the rest of the code is strongly oriented on how `copied` was implemented:

```rust
pub struct IntoIterCopied<I>
{
    into_iter: I,
}

impl<I> IntoIterCopied<I>
{
    pub fn new(iter: I) -> Self {
        IntoIterCopied{
            into_iter: iter,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a,I,T> IntoIterator for IntoIterCopied<I>
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = &'a T>,
    T: 'a + Copy
{
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = std::iter::Copied<I::IntoIter>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.into_iter.into_iter().copied()
    }
}

pub trait IntoIterCopiedExt {
    fn into_copied<'a, T>(self) -> IntoIterCopied<Self>
    where
        Self: Sized + IntoIterator<Item = &'a T>,
        T: 'a + Copy
    {
        IntoIterCopied::new(self)
    }
}

impl<T> IntoIterCopiedExt for T
where T: IntoIterator {}
```

I thought I could now use the function `non_consuming` like so:

```rust
let into_iter_adap = (&vec![0usize,1,2]).into_copied();
non_consuming(&into_iter_adap);
```

However this is the error I got:

```
error[E0277]: `&IntoIterCopied<&Vec<usize>>` is not an iterator
  --> src/main.rs:46:19
   |
40 | fn non_consuming<'a,I>(_: &'a I)
   |    ------------- required by a bound in this
41 | where &'a I: std::iter::IntoIterator<Item = usize>
   |              ------------------------------------- required by this bound in `non_consuming`
...
46 |     non_consuming(&into_iter_adap);
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `&IntoIterCopied<&Vec<usize>>` is not an iterator
   |
   = help: the trait `Iterator` is not implemented for `&IntoIterCopied<&Vec<usize>>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoIterator` for `&IntoIterCopied<&Vec<usize>>`
```

I'm not really sure what the error is telling me. I implemented `IntoIterator` for `IntoIterCopied` but not for `&IntoIterCopied`, so why is the note telling me it would be implemented?

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=271356806baae04ab5c5e0b955b73c21)

Comment: Your `where` clause doesn't enforce that `I` is an `IntoIterator` but rather that `&I` is an `IntoIterator`. Just because `IntoIterCopied` is an `IntoIterator` doesn't mean that `&IntoIterCopied` is.

Answer (score 1):

There's an amount of noise here that distracts from what I imagine the goal to be. Let's take one thing at a time.

### Relax the signature of `non_consuming`

`non_consuming` has an unnecessarily limiting function signature: it demands that its argument be in the form `&I`, when all it actually requires is that the argument be `IntoIterator<Item = usize>`. This means that even if you *had* a `Vec<usize>` to pass (which you don't, but bear with me), you couldn't pass it to `non_consuming`; you'd be forced to keep it around in the caller. Deciding whether to consume or not, when it's not necessary, should be the *caller's* problem; this function shouldn't care. We can rewrite it without loss of generality:

```
fn maybe_consuming<II>(_: II)
where
    II: std::iter::IntoIterator<Item = usize>,
{
}
```

`maybe_consuming` will still accept any reference that `non_consuming` would, because `II` can be a reference.

### Replace `IntoIterCopied`

You don't need to wrap an `IntoIterator` in a struct to give it an `into_copied` method. (If you wanted `&a_vec` to always yield `usize`s, you might consider wrapping `a_vec`, but it doesn't seem necessary in this case.) You can just make an extension trait that provides `into_copied` and returns a `Copied<Self::IntoIter>` directly.

```
pub trait IntoCopied {
    fn into_copied<'a, T>(self) -> std::iter::Copied<Self::IntoIter>
    where
        Self: Sized + IntoIterator<Item = &'a T>,
        T: 'a + Copy,
    {
        self.into_iter().copied()
    }
}

impl<I> IntoCopied for I where I: IntoIterator {}
```

Because `Copied<I>` is an `Iterator` and therefore implements `IntoIterator`, any code that worked with the original version should still work with this one.

### Fix the caller

Since `maybe_consuming` has been changed to allow non-references, we can just pass `.into_copied()` directly to it:

```
fn main() {
    let vec_ref = &vec![0usize, 1, 2];
    maybe_consuming(vec_ref.into_copied());
}
```

Comment: `non_consuming` has this signature because in my project it will delegate the collections to other functions. Such it has to be able to know that the reference of the collection is iterable (or that the iterable is `copy`).
[Here is the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c6a2fe286d41444852e15a5cd95c421d) to show what I'm trying to say.
The remaining improvements can't be done without the relaxation of the signature (I think).

Comment: I added a paragraph specifying what I wanted to achieve with `into_copied`. I'm sorry for the inconvenience, should have been there from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of @kmdreko, I got the code to compile. I only had to implement `IntoIterator` for `&IntoIterCopied`, so I added

```
impl<'a,I,T> IntoIterator for &'a IntoIterCopied<I>
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = &'a T> + Copy,
    T: 'a + Copy
{
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = std::iter::Copied<I::IntoIter>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.into_iter.into_iter().copied()
    }
}
```

to the code and it just worked fine.