# How do I write a custom `IntoIterator` implementation that simply reverses the iteration?

Tags: rust, iterator, traits

I'm a Rust newbie and I'm trying to implement a custom `struct` that has `Vec`. I'd like this custom struct to be iterable and that iterates on the inner `Vec` in reverse order.

So far what I understood is that I need to implement the `IntoIterator` trait and eventually a custom `Iterator` to which the `IntoIterator` transforms the custom struct. Since I just want to reverse the iteration on the `Vec`, I was thinking to re-use what the standard lib offers already.

This is my struct:

```
pub struct BitMap {
    content: Vec<u64>,
}
```

and this is how I was trying to implement the `IntoIterator`:

```
impl<'a> iter::IntoIterator for &'a BitMap {
    type Item = u64;
    type IntoIter = iter::Rev<slice::Iter<'a, Self::Item>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        (&(self.content)).iter().rev()
    }
}
```

But the compiler complains about:

```
47  |     type IntoIter = iter::Rev<slice::Iter<'a, Self::Item>>;
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `u64`, found reference
```

I'm struggling to understand how I can achieve this simple thing.

**UPDATE**

Thanks [E_net4 says don't copy that](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233251/e-net4-says-dont-copy-that) for your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67296610/3276106)!

Considering that you mentioned that your solution would require copying the elements, I tried to implement a version that tries to avoid it and this is what I came up with:

```
impl<'a> iter::IntoIterator for &'a BitMap {
    type Item = u64;
    type IntoIter = BitMapIterator<'a>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        BitMapIterator::new(&self.content)
    }
}

pub struct BitMapIterator<'a> {
    content: &'a Vec<u64>,
    index: usize,
}

impl<'a> BitMapIterator<'a> {
    fn new(content: &'a Vec<u64>) -> Self {
        BitMapIterator {
            content,
            index: content.len(),
        }
    }
}

impl iter::Iterator for BitMapIterator<'_> {
    type Item = u64;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index == 0 {
            None
        } else {
            self.index -= 1;
            Some(self.content[self.index])
        }
    }
}
```

But as you can see, this required me to implement also a custom Iterator and make it public. This seems to do what I want and if I'm understanding correctly without copying the elements, but I don't know how idiomatic this solution is and it basically doesn't re-use anything provided by std lib.

Comment: Please avoid [building up follow-up questions on the same post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290747). Nevertheless, you might have misunderstood what the copy adaptor does, so I have edited the answer. It does not eagerly make a copy of the struct, so it does not need to allocate any extra memory.

Comment: You're right, sorry for the follow-up. Thanks for mentioning what the `copy` does and specifying that it's not eager. On the other hand, am I correct in assuming that the snippet I posted in the update avoids copying at all? Despite being the cost of copying `u64` low, I'm thinking at scenarios where the size of the `Vec` could be huge such as 2^64.

Comment: There is still a copy from the moment you do `self.content[self.index]`. The syntax will implicitly dereference that position in the vector, which still requires a copy because values cannot be moved out of a borrow. Relevant questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904864 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344641 I would say that your implementation is very unlikely to bring any performance or efficiency improvements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `.iter()` on a vector creates a non-owning iterator of items, which will be behind immutable references. And an iterator of `&u64` items does not fulfill the role of an iterator of `u64` items.

Considering that `u64` is cheap to copy, adapting that iterator with [`.copied`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied) is enough to obtain an iterator returning the actual values. A copied iterator is lazy, leaving that it only copies the items as they are traversed.

```
use std::{iter, slice};

pub struct BitMap {
    content: Vec<u64>,
}

impl<'a> iter::IntoIterator for &'a BitMap {
    type Item = u64;
    type IntoIter = iter::Copied<iter::Rev<slice::Iter<'a, Self::Item>>>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        self.content.iter().rev().copied()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=00b864dad66f5719e5ba17ab22f3baa1)

See also:

- [What is the difference between iter and into_iter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter)
- [Creating the method copied for IntoIterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66259256/creating-the-method-copied-for-intoiterator)

Comment: Since `into_iter` consumes the struct and the vector is owned by struct (i.e. it is consumed too), it's probably appropriate to just use `self.content.into_iter()` instead and adjust the associated type to use `vec::IntoIter`.

Comment: That would be a possible implementation, @Cerberus, but a different one altogether. This one in particular is aligned with the question in the characteristic that it does not consume the full struct, only the reference to it.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, missed the fact that it's `&BitMap` which is iterated over, not the `BitMap`.